# SharePoint 2013 problems - low performance and errors

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

We are facing problems with SharePoint 2013 Foundation with SQL Express.

Users are (there are total 50 of them, peak should be no more than 20) experiencing long latency and "Sorry, something went wrong" screens.

I analyzed logs tracing problems back with correlation IDs and here is what I found (couple of cases included):

> A large block of literal text was sent to sql (length 58462).  This
>   can result in blocking in sql and excessive memory use on the front
>   end.  Verify that no binary parameters are being passed as literals,
>   and consider breaking up batches into smaller components.  If this
>   request is for a SharePoint list or list item, you may be able to
>   resolve this by reducing the number of fields

And then there is a monstrous query, after the query there's error:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

Query seems to execute when List Item is queried from the database and probably as the warning from log file says it blocks SQL and slows portal.

Is there a way to change/correct this?

If there are any additional information that would be useful here, please let me know.

Comment: What's the specs on your server(s)? Sounds like they are underpowered

Comment: No, actually they are not. I will give you exact stats later when I can check them, but of the top of my head it's 16GiB of ram and 4 CPUS. What's more - when I am trying to "kill it" with jmeter all CPUs are @ 100% and it's still responding fine. When this low performance (long wait) occurs CPUs and disks are not utilized at all.

I think that this monstrous query that causes SQL blocks occurs only for certain items, and when I am running jmeter with different list items it works fine.

I will be able to test it on Monday.

Comment: did you try to enable the Developer dashboard and check exactly which thing is causing this issue.

Comment: I'll check that first thing tomorrow morning - maybe my friends tried it - I need to ask. But from what I there is a problem with too many items being pulled out of the database which creates monstrous SQL queries. Will follow that lead and try to diagnose this further with developer dashboard.